# How to get the through instance in a has_many :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

I have a has_many :through relation models like:

```
#foo
has_many :bars, through: link
has_many :links

#link
belongs_to :bar
belongs_to :foo

#bar
has_many :foos, through: link
has_many :links
```

In a situation where I have a instance of a `foo` and a instance of a `bar` how can I get the specific `link` instance that joins the two together(if it exists)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
foo.links.where(bar_id: bar.id).first
```

will do?

Comment: this is a piece of lore with omnipresent value

Answer (score 3):

I think you could do

```
foo.links.find_by_bar_id(bar.id)
```

Comment: This works too, but rewritten was first so I accepted his answer.